# How to write/set sub-node with multiple cdata xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, string, cdata

I try to produce XML like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movie>
<title><![CDATA[Con Air]]></title>
<plot><![CDATA[When the government puts all its rotten criminal eggs in one airborne basket, it's asking for trouble. Before you can say, "Pass the barf bag," the crooks control the plane, led by creepy Cyrus "The Virus" Grissom. Watching his every move is the just-released Cameron Poe, who'd rather reunite with his family. The action climaxes with an incredible crash sequence in Las Vegas.]]></plot>
<tagline><![CDATA[They were deadly on the ground; Now they have wings]]></tagline>
<year>1997</year>
<id>tt0118880</id>
<rating>65</rating>
<votes>93</votes>
<budget>75000000</budget>
<revenue>224012234</revenue>
<company><![CDATA[Touchstone Pictures]]></company>
<genre>
<name><![CDATA[Action]]></name>
<name><![CDATA[Adventure]]></name>
<name><![CDATA[Thriller]]></name>
</genre>
</movie>
```

I use C# XmlDocument to generate the XML File using serializable class below

```
[Serializable]
public class movie
{
    public movie()
    {
        this.genre = new Genre();
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public XmlCDataSection titleCDATA
    {
        get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(title); }
        set { title = value.Value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string plot { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("plot")]
    public XmlCDataSection plotCDATA
    {
        get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(plot); }
        set { plot = value.Value; }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string tagline { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("tagline")]
    public XmlCDataSection taglineCDATA
    {
        get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(tagline); }
        set { tagline = value.Value; }
    }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public int votes { get; set; }
    public long budget { get; set; }
    public long revenue { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string company { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("company")]
    public XmlCDataSection companyCDATA
    {
        get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(company); }
        set { company = value.Value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("genre")]
    public Genre genre { get; set; }


}

public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
    }

    public string[] name { get; set; }
}
```

But the output not as expected like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<movie>
<title><![CDATA[Monster House]]></title>
<plot><![CDATA[Monsters under the bed are scary enough, but what happens when an entire house is out to get you? Three teens aim to find out when they go up against a decrepit neighboring home and unlock its frightening secrets.]]></plot>
<tagline><![CDATA[The House is . . . ALIVE!]]></tagline>
<year>2006</year>
<id>tt0385880</id>
<rating>57</rating>
<votes>74</votes>
<budget>0</budget>
<revenue>0</revenue>
<company><![CDATA[Sony Pictures Entertainment]]></company>
<genre>
<name>
<string>Adventure</string>
<string>Animation</string>
<string>Comedy</string>
<string>Fantasy</string>
<string>Mystery</string>
<string>Science Fiction</string>
<string>Family</string>
</name>
</genre>
</movie>
```

How can I create sub-node xml like the genre sub-node in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue with element names called "string" instead of "name" should be solved by using proper annotation as covered in [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx) .

You'll have to modify you class a bit (and I'm not sure you can get CDATA for names, but it should be fine):

```
public class Movie
{
  ....
  [XmlArray("genre")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Name")]
  public string[] Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, and I also change the string[] type into XmlCDataSection[] so the output of XmlArrayItem in CDATA like the first example.

Here are the code:
<pre><code>public class Movie
{
  ....
  [XmlArray("genre")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Name")]
  public XmlCDataSection[] Genre { get; set; }
}</code></pre>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, and I also change the string[] type into XmlCDataSection[] so the output of XmlArrayItem in CDATA like the first example.<br>

Here are the code:
`
public class Movie
    {
    ....
    [XmlArray("genre")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Name")]
    public XmlCDataSection[] Genre { get; set; }
    }
`